# How to revert Intellij's Jupyter notebook to traditional style?

Tags: intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I use IntelliJ premium, I updated the whole app, and I saw a very annoying new output style of it's Jupyter notebook. Then I reinstalled an older version, I see the jupyter output is still in new format. I guess it is because of Jupyter's package update.
How can I have the old-style table format?
the new style shows only 10 rows and for every run, you should change 10 to a higher number which becomes annoying after a couple of minutes. It has gotten really slow too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Default page size for table outputs is 10 rows. Now you can change it manually or using dataframes' parameters like `display.max_rows` in pandas.

Also, it is the feature request regarding customizing default size https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-4297/Make-the-default-page-size-configurable.